# Haskell operation definition: Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of `==' from the context (Num a)

Tags: haskell

I need to define an operation (<-<) that returns True for a <-< b if the number of real divisors of b is greater than the number of divisors of a. I also need to use the declaration:

```
(<-<) :: Num a => a -> a -> Bool
```

I tried the following expression:

```
a <-< b = ((length [x | x<-[2..b-1], b `mod` x == 0]) > (length [x | x<-[1..a], a `mod` x == 0]))
```

and it works fine, but only if I don't use the declaration I was given. With that, I get the usual errors like

```
Could not deduce (Enum a) arising from the arithmetic sequence 2 .. b - 1 from the context (Num a)
Could not deduce (Integral a) arising from a use of mod from the context (Num a)
Could not deduce (Eq a) arising from a use of == from the context (Num a)
```

I know that I can get rid of the error by modifying the declaration, or even removing it completely, but my task is to write an expression with that declaration. How is that possible?

Comment: While I expect it could be done with some expensive search through the multiplication table, I would suggest talking to your TA/professor/whoever assigned this. Perhaps they overlooked what was needed, and they will definitely know what is ethical to reveal and what isn't in a way we can't.

Comment: Can you think of a faster way to count the divisors? Can you separate the different pieces of this code into separate functions? If I were in your shoes, I'd probably write three functions here instead of one. One of the nice things about functional programming is that it makes it easy to break programs into little pieces. You should take advantage of that! I recently wrote several pages of code to implement one function. When I was finished, I realized I could use several of the big pieces I'd written, unchanged, to implement another function. Save time!

Answer (score 1):

Until recently, `Eq` was a superclass of `Num`. I bet the assignment dates back to when that was the case. You should let the person who gave the assignment know that the signature is no longer sufficient in modern GHC.

Furthermore, that signature would *never* have worked without `Integral` for `mod`!

So I bet this is just an oversight on their part.